# Quad IR pickup output inconsistencies

Tags: infrared, photodiode, optoelectronics

I've designed a quad IR pickup for a stringed instrument. The pickup works well, except that the output level of each string is different. Some strings (particularly the left two channels in the schematic) are hotter than other strings. I'm thinking that this is either because A) perhaps the circuit is not optimized to have each of the four channels receive/send proper current or B) each string requires a different resistance (hence the potentiometer) for each IR LED to come 'into focus' for the IR pickup.

Thoughts?

[image]
Quad IR pickup schematic

Comment: are all four strings the same? ... that do you mean by `strings are hotter than other strings`?

Comment: Strings 1 & 2 are quite a bit hotter than 3 &4. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I did not ask what `left two channels` means ... I asked what `hotter` means

Comment: The signal amplitude is greater in the two left channels than the right two.

Comment: swap the strings between channels 1 and 3, and between channels 2 and 4

Comment: OK - this is the voltage output peak to peak with strings 1-4 before swapping: 2, 1.4, 0.8, 0.6. This is the voltage after swapping: 1.8, 1.7, 0.6, 0.6. Differences in how I plucked the string might account for some slight differences between test #1 and test #2.

Comment: I think I figured it out - after some testing I realized that string tension has a significant influence on the amplitude each string can produce. Thank you all for your help.